# magento store url occurs twice on store 2 of 3

Tags: magento-1.9, full-page-cache, redis, template-directive

I am about to got nuts trying to figure this one out. I have 3 stores, camping, fishing and hunting all using the base URL with redirect to the store URL. i.e URL nilandtrading.com/fishing, but if I got to use any links on the page they turn into URL nilandtrading.com/fishing/fishing/some.html.

Also an exact duplicate of other BLOCKS:

```
<ul>
<li class="level0 nav-information parent" onmouseout="toggleMenu(this,0)" onmouseover="toggleMenu(this,1)"><a href="{{store url="information"}}">Information</a>
<ul class="level0">
<li class="level1 nav-about"><a href="{{store url="about"}}"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
<li class="level1 nav-conditions"><a href="{{store url="conditions"}}"><span>Conditions of Use </span></a></li>
<li class="level1 nav-privacy-policy"><a href="{{store url="privacy-policy"}}"><span>Privacy Policy</span></a></li>
<li class="level1 nav-security-policy"><a href="{{store url="security-policy"}}"><span>Security Policy</span></a></li>
<li class="level1 nav-shipping"><a href="{{store url="shipping"}} "><span>Shipping &amp; Delivery </span></a></li>
<li class="level1 nav-faq"><a href="{{store url="faq"}} "><span>FAQ</span></a></li>
<li class="level1 nav-affiliate"><a href="{{store url="affiliates"}} "><span>Affiliate Program</span></a></li>
<li class="level1 nav-coupons"><a href="{{store url="coupons"}} "><span>Coupon Codes</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="level0 nav-satisfaction"><a href="{{store url="customer"}}"><span>Customer Satisfaction</span></a>
<ul class="level0">
<li class="level1 nav-satisfaction"><a href="{{store url="satisfaction"}}"><span>Satisfaction Guarantee</span></a></li>
<li class="level1 nav-3in1"><a href="{{store url="3in1"}}"><span>3 in 1 Guarantee</span></a></li>
<li class="level1 nav-testimonial"><a href="{{store url="testimonial"}}"><span>Testimonials</span></a></li>
<li class="level1 nav-shopper"><a href="{{store url="shopper"}}"><span>Shopper Approved</span></a></li>
<li class="level1 nav-shopper"><a href="{{store url="reward-points"}}"><span>Loyalty Reward Points</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
.... and more
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Works on the 1st and 3rd store but not the [fishing] store

I have nuked any cache in Reis and the database and deleted URL redirects and turned of Amasty full page cache and it make no difference. I have double checked the store URL's and compared them to working backups for magento 1.6.2.0. I am trying to do magento 1.9.3.4 and since I don't want to repurchase so many extensions I will not do magento 2.x any time soon. That any I hate having to beta test magento's new versions. I think that is why they have CE so they can use us to test for what the include in the EE versions, tried of it. Learned the hard way I could not update a 1.6.2.0 database to 1.8.x or greater with out numerous errors!!

My config looks like this:
[image: system>>web>>secure]

So I am struggling and I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this has become a Redis or cache question? It seems no mater how many times I made the changes on the Magento back-end the URL was not updating in the database as I did eventually find the error the core_config_data. Rather strange is what was in the database seem to be right on the back-end. To get the correct value to stick I had to disable magento and edit the database directly. Seems I was able to do this by changing enough /app/etc/modules/ = false so effectively putting magento into constant error reports, non functional and made the edits.

Maybe I have to take a better look at Redis cache? Perhaps I need to take a look at redis SNAPSHOTTING, as the suggested way It save might be in error in the /etc/redis/redis.conf
Any Redis experts know if this might be what is up?